# How to redirect to clean links with this code

Tags: redirect, urls

I have a website uses wildcard*

i made a custom page called custom-page.php

i used this code to access to this custom page

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \h/custom-page\h
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/custom-page\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ x.php?id=%1 [L]
```

**My problem :**

this code makes this url :

> subdomain.domain.com/custom-page

works fine and access my custom-page.php

but also when you type

> subdomain.domain.com/custom-page.php?id=subdomain

it access too

**What i Need :**

what i need is when user enters this url

> subdomain.domain.com/custom-page.php?id=subdomain

it automatics redirect him to

> subdomain.domain.com/custom-page

how can i modify this code